# Access Sql Server through Ruby Active Record JDBC

Tags: sql-server, ruby, activerecord, jdbc, jruby

I've been attempting to connect to a remote JDBC/SqlServer database using Active Record in Ruby (specifically JRuby). Here is my code:

```
require 'activerecord'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
                      :adapter => 'sqlserver',
                      :username => '<username>',
                      :password => '<password>',
                      :database => '<database_name>',
                      :url => '<database_url>',
)
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

puts @connection
```

I've also put 'jdbc' as the adapter, and that also did not work.

And here is an abbreviated version of the error I am getting:

```
NameError: cannot load Java class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
                  for_name at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:286
           get_proxy_class at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34
      block in java_import at uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:49
                       map at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486
               java_import at uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:36
     block in driver_class at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.23/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/driver.rb:24
               module_eval at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2833
     block in driver_class at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.23/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/driver.rb:23
              synchronized at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaObject.java:257
```

It's not so much a specific problem but more that I'm just unsure where to go from here. Using the 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' in pure Ruby doesn't work because of the JDBC on the server. (I might be misusing the terms here, I'm rather unfamiliar with how databases work.)

However, the jdbc/sqlserver gems seem to be not well-supported or out of date. There's probably no silver bullet for this, but any kind of direction would be of enormous help.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter/README.rdoc

Comment: It was my understanding that that gem was out of date? But I'll give it a try.

Comment: that is the gem you are using `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` I simply provided the instructions from their README (since it was buried) on how to install the correct driver ( which is your issue) and how to configure ActiveRecord to use it

Comment: The driver that is provided by microsoft that the gem needs to work correctly seems to now longer be offered. When I try to access the Ruby version, it tells me to install the 'tiny_tds' gem, which only works in Ruby, not JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to `require 'active_record'`, no?

And I am not sure you need the `require 'arel'`. That is the low level sql builder/formatter implemented by active_record.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlserver",
  :host => "SqlServerHostName",
  :database => "HostDbName"
)
```

Comment: Haha, I'll put it in the question for clarity, but this file is just in a project with a bunch of random things I've been doing to test out how things work. I believe activerecord is required in one of the other files.

What is referred to by 'host name'? Does that have anything to do with the URL? This is a remote database, which I will also add into the question.

Comment: Blind leading the blind, here. You're sure you have the MS JDBC drivers installed, I've only worked with JDBC (very little) within an IDE, and it took care of the driver issue for me. Host name is the server name hosting SqlServer, and database is the db in that installation. May I ask what you are attempting with `arel`?

Comment: FYI - I am using the Microsoft's SqlServer JDBC v6.0.8112.100.

Comment: I had gotten an error about it at some point so I included it, but I have actually removed it since and everything is working. I ended up downloading the jar file for the MS-JDBC drivers, putting it into the project and using 'requires_relative' to bring it into my test.

Comment: I've gotten a lot closer. I'm using a URL to connect to the database, but then it's attempting to connect to the wrong port. I might try using IP:port as the host, but I'll explore some more options.